# Twitter Search API: result_type details?

Tags: twitter, twitter-search

The Twitter Search API documentation for the attribute `result_type` specifies three different options: mixed, recent, popular.

The documentation is vague about the differences between recent and popular. Does anyone know how the API uses these attributes? For example, does `recent` only query the last X hours? Does `popular` have a threshold for retweet count?

Documentantion: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/search/api-reference/get-search-tweets

Answer (score 1):

Popular only returns tweets if they meet a certain threshold, it might be based on favorites or another special algorithm. If a query does not yield any tweet that's not classified as "popular", it won't return any tweets.

I think recent is the default result_type if none is specified.